# How to set up the URL/URI for a Client Flow Authentication with Azure AD B2C?

Tags: authentication, xamarin, azure-active-directory, redirect, azure-ad-b2c

I am working with a mobile app as a Native Client, and trying to set up a simple log in through Azure AD B2C. I been following the documentation but still confused about how to set up correctly all the redirect URLs , as I am getting errors when redirecting the page after a user log in.

I just want to make sure what is the correct way of setting up the following values for a Mobile App Service (e.g. AppName with URL www. https ://AppName.azurewebsites.net) :

Custom redirect URI, in the B2C tenant properties.

Reply URL, in the Sing-Up Sign-In policy.

Allowed external redirect URL, in the Authentication/Authorization of the App service.

Allowed token audiences, in the Azure Active directory Settings.

Answer (score 0):

For a Client Managed Authentication flow you can configure the custom redirect URI to a URL scheme that uniquely identifies the mobile application followed by `://auth/` in B2C Tenant properties and same needs to be configured in the reply URL of the SignUp-SignIn policy.  Please refer to [Integrating Azure AD B2C with Mobile Apps](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/data-cloud/authentication/azure-ad-b2c-mobile-app) for more information.

Also, "Allowed External Redirect URL" for your authentication settings in Azure Portal would be `{url_scheme_of_your_app}://easyauth.callback` where {url_scheme_of_your_app} is the app name in Azure Portal. 
Please refer to [Add authentication to Xamarin Android App](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service-mobile/app-service-mobile-xamarin-android-get-started-users) for details.

In the "Allowed Token Audiences" field insert the App ID URL of the application registered earlier.